# How do I know if onSaveInstanceState() has been called so that I can avoid the IllegalStateException?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

When a user selects an item in the Navigation Drawer, my app kicks off a Handler which, after waiting for the drawer to close, calls the code to replace the fragment in my main Activity. However, if the device has been rotated during the delay, I get an IllegalStateException.

I've read this brilliant article about fragment transactions and lifecycles, but I'm not sure how to handle this in my code. I understand that I should not try to commit a transaction after `onSaveInstanceState()`. But how do I know if `onSaveInstanceState()` has been called? I want to do something like this.

```
navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(final MenuItem menuItem) {
        // close drawers
        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                goTo(menuItem); // swap in Fragment specified by menuItem
            }
        }, 300);
        return true;
    }
    });
...
private void goTo(menuItem) {
    if( alreadyCalledOnSaveInstanceState() {  // THIS
        return;
    }

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.item1:
            frag = new Fragment_Grade_Calculator();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.zoom_exit).replace(R.id.main_frag_container, frag)
                    .commit();
            return true;
}
```

But I don't know of an equivalent to my made-up `alreadyCalledOnSaveInstanceState()`.

Comment: I ended up just putting a try/catch around my `goTo(menuItem)` call. It did the trick for my purposes--the fragment is never swapped. Better than crashing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not use onSaveInstanceState(), but onStop(). And don't commit a transaction after onStop() was invoked. And don't forget to allow committing your transaction after onStart() was invoked.

Comment: Are you saying that I should manually track whether `onSaveInstanceState()` or `onStop()` have been called?

Comment: This article is devoted to your issue: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/08/fragment-transaction-commit-state-loss.html

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, onSaveInstanceState() will never be called before onPause(). So as long as you are committing your fragment transactions in resumed state, you should be safe from hitting the IllegalStateException.

Comment: According to the docs, after android P, onSaveInstanceState is guaranteed to be called after onStop. But pre Android P, onSaveInstanceState will be called before onStop, and there is no guarantee whether it will happen before or after onPause.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)